# php form processing issue when processing script returns to the calling script

Tags: forms, call, processing, back

Problem:
form processing script throws error when returning back to the calling script which is the user entry form.

error message

Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /inc/utilities.inc.php on line 3 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Connection in /inc/dbconn.php on line 5

The code is a bit too large to copy past all of it so im just going to focus on the problem area.
newproject.php calls -> savenewproject.php. if savenewproject.php finds error it returns back to newproject.php to display error message.

//newproject.php - parts of the code that i believe is  the problem area.

```
<?php
include('../inc/utilities.inc.php'); 
include('header.php');
if (!empty($errorString))
    {    echo '<div class="error">' . $errorString . '</div>';    }

    if (!empty($successString))
    {    $emailaddress = ''; 
        $budget = '';
        $projecttitle ='';
        $projectdescription = '';
        echo '<div id="divfadeout" class="success">' . $successString . '</div>';
    }
?>
<form name ='newProject' action="../inc/savenewproject.php"   enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
the rest are form fields
</form>
```

// include('../inc/utilities.inc.php'); - appears in both script

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = (isset($_SESSION['user'])) ? $_SESSION['user']: null;
include("../inc/dbconn.php");
?>
```

// savenewproject.php - copy/pasting what i believed to be the problem area.

```
if(count($fieldErrors) > 0)
{    $errorString = '<p>There was an error processing the form.</p>';
    $errorString . 'ul>';
    foreach($fieldErrors as $errorVal)
    {    $errorString .= "<li>$errorVal</li>"; }
        $errorString .= '</ul>';
    include ('../layout/newproject.php');               
}
else
{
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like i answered my own question.. 
instead of include i used request once and it seems to have fixed the probelm..